# Modify JsonNode of unknown JSON dynamically in Java

Tags: jackson, jsonpath

I am trying to modify a JSON (of an unknown structure) where the JsonPath and its equivalent XML Xpath is known to me.

I have tired using `com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath` library for the same.
The problem with JsonPath is, it returns me the value but I am not able to modify the Target Node.

Follows is my code snippet for the same

```
JsonPath.read(jsonFile, jsonPath);
JsonPath.parse(jsonPath);
System.out.println("Author: "+JsonPath.read(jsonFile, jsonPath));
```

I tried using Jackson as mentioned in [previously asked quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997362/how-to-modify-jsonnode-in-java), But it needs to be traversed node by node as follows

```
((ObjectNode) parent).put(fieldName, newValue);
```

which I cannot do due to unknown structure.

I have tried the answer given to the question [recursively parse JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111857/parse-recursively-unknown-json-input-structure-in-java) but it says how to parse not modify

I need to do the follows

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree("Json in form of String");
((JsonNode)(root.get("JsonPath")).set("New Value");
```

Is there any way in which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JsonNode` objects are immutable so you can't modify them. What you can do is replace a `JsonNode` with another one. A cast to `ObjectNode` is also required to expose the required methods. First find the parent of the node you want to replace :

```
JsonNode node = root.findParent("JsonPath");
```

Then use either of these 2 methods to replace it with a new one:

```
((ObjectNode) node).remove("JsonPath");           // remove current node
((ObjectNode) node).put("JsonPath", "New Value"); // add new one with new value
```

or

```
((ObjectNode) node).replace("JsonPath", new TextNode("New Value"));
```